# How to split range refrence of addresses into elements of one dimenaional array

Tags: vba, excel

I have a variable type variant stored in it cells addresses and range addresses

e.g:

```
Dim cells_addresses as variant
Cells_addresses="$A$1,$C$3:$F$3,$F$4"
```

Now I want to use a split function or any other sub or function in VBA to split those  cells addresses in one dimensional array as the following:

```
Output_Array="$A$1","$C$3","$D$3","$E$3","$F$3","$F$4"
```

Anyone has an idea how to split range of addresses into individual elements of an array?

Comment: You could simply loop through all of them with `For each cell in Range(Split(Cells_addresses, ",")(1))` (or something like that).

Comment: @walid attia  have you tried any of the solution provided below ? any feedback ?

Comment: I did not try yet. I had some physical troubles.I will try tomorrow as I feel better.but really I appreciate the great answers from you .thanks slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or like this...

```
Dim cells_addresses As Variant
Dim OutputArr()
Dim cell As Range
Dim str() As String
Dim i As Long, ii As Long
cells_addresses = "$A$1,$C$3:$F$3,$F$4"
str() = Split(cells_addresses, ",")
For i = 0 To UBound(str)
    For Each cell In Range(str(i))
        ii = ii + 1
        ReDim Preserve OutputArr(1 To ii)
        OutputArr(ii) = cell.Address
    Next cell
Next i
MsgBox Join(OutputArr, ", ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
Function SplitRanges(RangeString As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ranges As Variant, v As Variant
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    ranges = Split(RangeString, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ranges)
        n = n + Range(ranges(i)).Cells.Count
    Next i
    ReDim v(1 To n)
    i = 0
    For j = 0 To UBound(ranges)
        For Each c In Range(ranges(j)).Cells
            i = i + 1
            v(i) = c.Address
        Next c
    Next j
    SplitRanges = v
End Function
```

Tested like:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = "$A$1,$C$3:$F$3,$F$4"
    Debug.Print Join(SplitRanges(s), ",")
End Sub
```

Output:

```
$A$1,$C$3,$D$3,$E$3,$F$3,$F$4
```

Comment: Since you're the only Pure mathematician here, do you know how to benchmark your solution performance with mine ? the faster gets a +1 :)

Comment: @ShaiRado VBA is a pain to benchmark and I have to work right now on a power point presentation for a class later on today. I suspect that your approach is quicker when the number of cells is <= 1000 since I take the extra pass over the data to pre-allocate the array and have more calls to `Range()`. Using a single call to `Range()` like you did is a clever approach.

Comment: @ShaiRado The power point is on baseball analytics using R. When I have more time I want to convert some of the R tools we've studied into VBA macros. I saw that Israel had a team in the World Baseball Classic this year, one which did better than expected. Was it followed much there?

Comment: Not really :) people here are more into soccer (god knows why)

Answer (score 2):

You can set an `Range` with the `Cells_addresses` values you provided. After, loop through the `Range.Areas` , and nested underneath loop through each `Area` cells, and each one add to your `Output_Array`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitRangeAddrrtoArray()

Dim cells_addresses As Variant
Dim UnionRng As Range
Dim RngArea As Range
Dim C As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim Output_Array() As Variant

cells_addresses = "$A$1,$C$3:$F$3,$F$4"
ReDim Output_Array(0 To 1000) ' init array size >> will optimize later

Set UnionRng = Range(cells_addresses) '<-- Set a Range with the cells addresses provided
' loop through range's areas in case there are multiple areas
For Each RngArea In UnionRng.Areas
    For Each C In RngArea ' loop through the area's cells
        Output_Array(i) = C.Address
        i = i + 1
    Next C
Next RngArea
ReDim Preserve Output_Array(0 To i - 1) '<-- resize to actual populated size

End Sub
```

Comment: Redo  it works very well with me .thanks slot the code is perfect

Comment: Redo , i do not know how

Comment: @walidattia but you just did :)